# Failed to create kubernetes pod on a windows server 2019 node

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, kubelet, windows-server-2019

I set up a master node on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine and followed the guide: https://kubernetes.io/ja/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/ to register a windows server 2019 node to the cluster successfully.

Now the kubelet has been started on powershell and the two nodes are ready.

On the windows machine, I run the command line: "kubectl create deployment --image=XXX(A windows server 2019 image) webadmin-app" to create a deployment on the windows node.

When creating the pod, kubelet reports the following log messages:

W0821 17:37:03.003768   99524 pod_container_deletor.go:77] Container "dee4daa76a9e60e0e68af75597092aa5cff517c7021a6ef7579f77f662f2a163" not found in pod's containers

W0821 17:37:03.071774   99524 helpers.go:289] Unable to create pod sandbox due to conflict. Attempting to remove sandbox "dee4daa76a9e60e0e68af75597092aa5cff517c7021a6ef7579f77f662f2a163"

E0821 17:37:03.108764   99524 remote_runtime.go:200] CreateContainer in sandbox "62ff282461eba2fae24a66b7d38ccca43b224c74320dbb5a0a4659b4c4446eb7" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/k8s_webadmin-site_webadmin-app-757c7455cf-nms75_default_7ac60567-f9e2-4c04-aead-c6957200c961_0" is already in use by container "dee4daa76a9e60e0e68af75597092aa5cff517c7021a6ef7579f77f662f2a163". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

E0821 17:37:03.109762   99524 kuberuntime_manager.go:801] container start failed: CreateContainerError: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/k8s_webadmin-site_webadmin-app-757c7455cf-nms75_default_7ac60567-f9e2-4c04-aead-c6957200c961_0" is already in use by container "dee4daa76a9e60e0e68af75597092aa5cff517c7021a6ef7579f77f662f2a163". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

E0821 17:37:03.113766   99524 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod 7ac60567-f9e2-4c04-aead-c6957200c961 ("webadmin-app-757c7455cf-nms75_default(7ac60567-f9e2-4c04-aead-c6957200c961)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "webadmin-site" with CreateContainerError: "Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/k8s_webadmin-site_webadmin-app-757c7455cf-nms75_default_7ac60567-f9e2-4c04-aead-c6957200c961_0" is already in use by container "dee4daa76a9e60e0e68af75597092aa5cff517c7021a6ef7579f77f662f2a163". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name."

Such failed messages keeps generating when creating the pod.

So I listed the docker containers using "docker ps" during the pod creation period. It seems that the kubelet keeps creating and removing containers(which are based on the specified image XXX).

How can I resolve such failure to create a deployment on the windows node?

Update:

I can create a deployment if --image is set to mcr.microsoft.com/k8s/core/pause:1.2.0 .
However if I use another image which is based on windows nano server. I got the deployment failed.
I caught up some error logs from kubelet output:

W0826 17:58:14.903662  127340 cri_stats_provider_windows.go:89] Failed to get HNS endpoint "" with error 'json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type hns.HNSEndpoint', continue to get stats for other endpoints

E0826 17:58:14.940665  127340 cni.go:364] Error adding default_webadmin-app-757c7455cf-5c5nf/9a37dab965d1b006c4c2ec70619b3a4bb42dd39dad8c0ce1baf39eab634da3d5 to network flannel/vxlan0: error while ProvisionEndpoint(9a37dab965d1b006c4c2ec70619b3a4bb42dd39dad8c0ce1baf39eab634da3d5_vxlan0,39EA65C2-C0F9-4870-8B7A-E2A1DBF5CD9D,9a37dab965d1b006c4c2ec70619b3a4bb42dd39dad8c0ce1baf39eab634da3d5): The virtual machine or container was forcefully exited.

E0826 17:58:14.942663  127340 cni_windows.go:59] error while adding to cni network: error while ProvisionEndpoint(9a37dab965d1b006c4c2ec70619b3a4bb42dd39dad8c0ce1baf39eab634da3d5_vxlan0,39EA65C2-C0F9-4870-8B7A-E2A1DBF5CD9D,9a37dab965d1b006c4c2ec70619b3a4bb42dd39dad8c0ce1baf39eab634da3d5): The virtual machine or container was forcefully exited.

W0826 17:58:14.943663  127340 docker_sandbox.go:400] failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: networkPlugin cni failed on the status hook for pod "webadmin-app-757c7455cf-5c5nf_default": error while ProvisionEndpoint(9a37dab965d1b006c4c2ec70619b3a4bb42dd39dad8c0ce1baf39eab634da3d5_vxlan0,39EA65C2-C0F9-4870-8B7A-E2A1DBF5CD9D,9a37dab965d1b006c4c2ec70619b3a4bb42dd39dad8c0ce1baf39eab634da3d5): The virtual machine or container was forcefully exited.

From the error messages, it seems that it is the container's image that caused the pod's failure. Did I miss anything when I was setting up my own image? Why the network plugin failed to work for my created image but works for the image mcr.microsoft.com/k8s/core/pause:1.2.0 ?

Comment: Try `docker container prune` and let me know if it worked. @Dennis

Comment: I have some new updates above. It seems that it is the image that causes the pod failure. Image mcr.microsoft.com/k8s/core/pause:1.2.0  's pod works, but my own created image failed.